# Can't open a network file in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, file-permissions

I have a WCF WSDualHttpBinding service. The service is contained in a WindowsService with account type LocalSystem.

The service is attempting to access a network file stored on another machine on the same network as the service, e.g. `\\dataStoreMachine\\myshare\\fileToOpen.txt` . If the service is running on dataStoreMachine (the same machine that stores the file), the file is opened succesfully. However, if the service is running on another machine in the network, the file is not found. Is this a permissions issue? I've given read permissions on the network share. Is there something that needs to be specified in the service bindings so it has the correct rights? The file can be browsed to from the machine running the service within win explorer, so I know the file is really at the location it's looking at it for.

Both machines on the network (a VMnet) are not on a specific domain, but have the same username, and blank passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LocalSystem account doesn't have any rights to network access. Assuming your servers are part of an ActiveDirectory domain, you should use the Network Service account to run the service. You'll need to give read permission for the share to the specific domain accounts assigned as the machine account of the servers. This is usually something like: YourDomain\MachineId123 where the MachineId123 is the actual machine name in the domain.

If you servers aren't in a domain, then you can use the synchronized passwords on identical local accounts technique. I would avoid this if at all possible because in the real world, it is very easily broken by a password change. Each server would have a **local machine** account named something like File123Shared and would have the same password as the same account on the other machines. You would run your service using that local account after configuring it to be able to run as a service and any other permissions it may need.